# VB.net / SQL Datatype that can store numbers, comma, decimal(2places) and vbcrlf?

Tags: vb.net

I always get a "String or binary data would be truncated" i have searched google for an answers but i cannot find the same values for my textbox.

In my program, i have a textbox(multiLine) which has a value of number,comma,decimal(2places) & vbCrlf which look like this.

```
1,234,567.89
      9,876,543.21
```

the above figure is an example of the value which my textbox have. (NOTE: NOTICE CAREFULLY THE ABOVE FIGURES HAS 2 COMMA BECAUSE IT IS IN MILLION), I dont know what is the reason behind it but if it has only 1COMMA, my code works perfectly fine like

```
123,456.78
      987,654.32
```

I have set my vb.net data type as string, decimal, double and object but i still get the same error. With regards to my SQL datatype, i have already set it to varchar, nvarchar, char but still get the same error. Here is my code:

```
*This is my CLASS code title SQLControl

Public Sub AddToJournalEntry(DrCrAmount As Object)
    Try
        Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO JournalEntry (DrCrAmount) " & _
                                  "VALUES (" & _
                                  "'" & DrCrAmount & "') "
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

*This my code in my frmMain

Dim sql As New SQLControl

Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click

    Dim format1 As String = "{0,-10} {1,12}"

    Dim Line1Amount, Line2Amount As String

    If lbl1.Text = "Dr" Then
        Line1Amount = String.Format(format1, txtAmount1.Text, vbNullString)
        Line1Amount = Line1Amount.TrimEnd(" ", vbNullString)
    ElseIf lbl1.Text = "Cr" Then
        Line1Amount = String.Format(format1, vbNullString, txtAmount1.Text)
        Line1Amount = Line1Amount.TrimEnd(" ", vbNullString)
    Else
        Line1Amount = String.Format(format1, vbNullString, vbNullString)
        Line1Amount = Line1Amount.TrimEnd(" ", vbNullString)
        lbl1.Text = vbNullString
    End If

    If lbl2.Text = "Dr" Then
        Line2Amount = String.Format(format1, txtAmount2.Text, vbNullString)
        Line2Amount = Line2Amount.TrimEnd(" ", vbNullString)
    ElseIf lbl2.Text = "Cr" Then
        Line2Amount = String.Format(format1, vbNullString, txtAmount2.Text)
        Line2Amount = Line2Amount.TrimEnd(" ", vbNullString)
    Else
        Line2Amount = String.Format(format1, vbNullString, vbNullString)
        Line2Amount = Line2Amount.TrimEnd(" ", vbNullString)
        lbl2.Text = vbNullString
    End If

    Dim myString2 As String = Line1Amount & vbCrLf & Line2Amount

    ****This code is to delete unnecessary spaces and new lines
    myString2 = myString2.TrimEnd(" ", vbNullString, Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return), Convert.ToChar(Keys.LineFeed))

    txtDrCrAmount.Text = myString2

End Sub

Private Sub btnRecord_Save_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRecord_Save.Click

    sql.AddToJournalEntry(txtDrCrAmount.Text)

End Sub
```

Note: My code is already edited and i already eliminated unnecessary code for your convenience.

Thank you =) by the way, im a newbie programmer.

Comment: there should not be any problem if you create the database table with datatype varchar.

Comment: hi Mr. Akhil, yes, it is working, but the problem is on the 2commas as mentioned above. it works fine in 1 comma.tnx

Comment: but the same worked for me with two and for even three commas and decimal.please check where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: can you pls specify the value for which the error "stirng or binary data would be truncated" occured.and also the length of datafield in sql.

Comment: thanks akhil, how can i mark as answered your comment? =) i got it and my program works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see the message....

```
string or binary data would be truncated
```

Think to yourself... The field is NOT big enough to hold my data.

Check the table structure of yourtable. I think you'll find that the length of field is NOT big enough to hold the data you are trying to insert. For example, if the journalentry field is a varchar(50) field, and you try to put 51 characters in to it, you will get this error.

Comment: thanks, i forgot to check the other tables which is related / linked with the other tables. there is a length issues and it is now solved. thank you so much